# Retrieve data from method in java

Tags: java, gwt

How can I retrieve a file from the following method:

```
public void getJson(String pathToFile) {
    String userUrl = DOMAIN_URL+pathToFile;
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(userUrl));
    JSONArray outerJsonArray;
    try {
        Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {

            }
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    try {
                        JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parse(response.getText());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray();
                        if (jsonArray != null) {

                        } else {
                            throw new JSONException();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {

    }
}
```

Now it is just void. I should retriwe the jsonArray variable

Comment: you have serious finger memory :)

Comment: Need more detail. Lots of `catch` blocks there that will hide any errors.

Comment: I should return jsonArray value. in other cases we can retriwe null.

Comment: sorry for being flippant.  when people misspell the same word over and over the same way it sometimes means their fingers do the typing not their minds :)

Comment: I am wondering there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't.

The request is asynchronous, so your method has to be asynchronous (non-blocking) too. You can pass something like an AsyncCallback (to reuse an existing interface) to your getJson method, and have your RequestCallback call it... back, with the JSONArray.

Technically speaking, that would be possible, but that's a [design choice](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideGettingUsedToAsyncCalls) in GWT to not allowing blocking AJAX requests.

[Embrace asynchrony!](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the declaration to

`public JSONArray getJson(String pathToFile) {`

After the line

`JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray();`

you can add

`return jsonArray;`

Now you have to be careful.  Obviously, you have some error checking conditions in case the array is null or an error occurs during reading.  It is up to you to design how to handle them: if the array is null, should you throw an exception or return the null value?  If there is an error reading, should you throw an exception, print an error, or return a null value?  These are considerations that your external interface will dictate.

Comment: Take a look.  while creating RequestCallback object i am implmenting it. it is interface and methods return void. so i can not write the return jsonArray; code there

Comment: If the interface requires a void modifier and you cannot change the interface, you're in some serious trouble.  If you made the interface, you will have to change the declaration of the method to include the return value.  If someone else owns the interface, you will have to get them to fix it.